# Pandas DataFrame export to_csv change dtype of columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hopefully a simple request.

I'm finding that when I build a DataFrame and set the column datatypes and then export it to csv it is doing a conversion on the datatype of a numerical string to an integer.

Such as a value might be "0000" and the csv ends up with value 0. But I need it to retain the number of characters in the string and save the csv as "0000".

Anyone know of a way to retain the string rather than the converted datatype?

Setting the datatype after import doesn't solve the issue (before anyone tells me I can set it on/after import), as it causes the issue that when converting the integer to a string you have to also configure the leading 0s on every import as well, which is not optimal.

Hoping I'm overlooking something simple.

(EDIT)
oh and my export line is just a simple export which is why it might be I'm just not realising the argument that needs to be provided.

```
df.to_csv("Test.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the column that causes the trouble? (Must be `object`.)

Comment: object is the current datatype listed for the column, but it was a numerical value converted into a string to retain it always being a 4 digit number including the padding needed to keep it at 4 digits when the numerical value is say 23 needs to be '0023', as the number is an identity

Comment: Wait, _how do you know_ the leading zeros have been removed? Did you open the CSV file in Excel?

Comment: Can you show a small sample of the Dataframe before it's exported?  Along with the datatypes?

Comment: @DyZ showed me the stupidity of my assumption. Thanks you DyZ. ASGM you did solve it and my original angle of doing the str on import works just fine. Thanks all for showing me my simple assumption of being wrong, didn't factor in Excel converting the data when opening it, teach me not to use a text editor first.

Comment: I bet I answered a similar question a couple of months ago, but I could not fine it...

Comment: I've had to show people the same answer previously fell into my own mistake.

Comment: @DyZ thanks again for making me realise to double check my assumption against as raw as possible information :) gonna be kicking myself for days overlooking that haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `df['your_column']` is the column you want to preserve, you can use the `dtype` argument in [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df.read_csv('temp.csv', dtype={'your_column': str})
```

If that's not working, are you sure your columns contain strings to begin with?  Because here's the behavior I see:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['0000', '0000', '0100',]})
>>> df1
      a
0  0000
1  0000
2  0100
>>> df1.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
>>> df2.read_csv('temp.csv', dtype={'a': str})
>>> df2
      a
0  0000
1  0000
2  0100
```

Maybe your problem isn't on export or import, but on creation.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': 0000, 0000, 0100]})
```

This is going to make a dataframe with values `0,0,100`.  If you want them to be strings, you need to create them as strings.