# Python: how do you prevent the conversion of a string to bool on save of dataframe to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Below you will see that I create a dataframe:

```
data = [['delivery@mail.foxitsoftwareaction.com','user1@corp.com','mail.foxitsoftwareaction.com','2019-12-10T00:44:10','false','false'],['delivery@mail.foxitsoftwareaction.com','user2@corp.com','mail.foxitsoftwareaction.com','2019-12-10T00:44:10','false','false']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['From','To','Sender_Sub_Fld','DateTime','Url','FileHash'])
```

You can see that the class is of type string:

```
type(df.Url.loc[0])
<class 'str'>
```

Then I write the dataframe to csv:

```
df.to_csv('/opt/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.5.8/import/sessions/new_neo_test_1.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

I of course new that there was an issue when I got the following message in Neo4j which usually only happens when there is a null value:

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.merge.relationship`: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

So I read the data back into a dataframe from the csv to find that the string is now a off type bool:

```
type(df3.Url.loc[0])
<class 'numpy.bool_'>
```

Why is this happening and how can I keep the `string` a `str` and prevent the conversion to `bool`

Comment: Specify the data-types when you read the csv. See this discussion for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/50165815/6770704

Comment: Or better yet, use a filetype that can serialize python objects that way datatypes persist between I/O operations. [`pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#pickling) is simple enough if everything is self-contained to you and/or trusted contributors (just switch `.to_csv` with `.to_pickle`). Otherwise you could try HDF5 or stuff like feather.