# Pandas export a dataframe as text column to csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with multiple columns and one of the column object type (values being 00001, 02679....)

On exporting this df a csv file the column values are converted to numeric and the resulting values are as 1, 2679....

How can the exported column retain the original value as 00001, 02679....?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue :

```py
df['your_col'] = df['your_col'].apply(lambda x: x.zfill(5))
```

Comment: this statement does not export column with original values as 00001, 02679....

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165799/pandas-dataframe-export-to-csv-change-dtype-of-columns)

does not provide an answer i am looking for. Please do not mark down my question if you are not sure on answering..